# History search for arguments in ZSH

Tags: linux, shell, unix, zsh

Does anyone know how to search backwards though argument history in ZSH.

For example assume the following session has already run:

```
cd fooDir
touch bar.txt
touch baz.txt quz.txt
```

Is there some combination, similar to Ctrl-R, that pulls back a argument from a partially completed command line.

For example if I start typing:

```
cat b
```

Then press whatever-the-key-is can I auto-complete `bar.txt`? A fruther press would presumably auto-complete `baz.txt`.

CTRL+R searches an entire command line and replaces whatever is already on the prompt. I'm looking for something that searches the history for just previous arguments and appends them to the pending command.

Answer (score 0):

There is `history-beginning-search-menu`, but you will need to enter a number for the match. Add this to your .zshrc:

```
bindkey '^P' history-beginning-search-menu
```

Then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to trigger the completion after typing the beginning of the command, then enter the match number.

Comment: Its a nice enough solution (incidentally you have to add `autoload -Uz history-beginning-search-menu; zle -N history-beginning-search-menu` to get it so it binds) but it also only works with one command history. Thanks for the tip though.